# Which of the following conditions must necessarily be true?

Tags: logic

Suppose that $\{A, B\}$ is a set of mutually exhaustive conditions, and that $\{C, D\}$ is another set of mutually exhaustive conditions.

If the following implications are true:

$$A \Longrightarrow C$$

and

$$B \Longrightarrow D,$$

then which of the conditions $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ must necessarily be true?

Comment: what makes you think any of them must be true?

Comment: You mean mutually **exclusive** conditions?

Comment: @yohBS, no I meant mutually *exhaustive* conditions.  But I guess the terminology would not matter here, since we are only dealing with *two* conditions in each set.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, I am not sure if any of them must be true.  Hence, my MSE question.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $B = \neg A$ and $D = \neg C$.  Therefore $A \implies C$ and $\neg A \implies \neg C$.  Hence $A \iff C$.

But neither $A$ nor $C$ need be true.

Comment: So it appears that what is true are the biconditionals

$$A \Longleftrightarrow C$$

and

$$B \Longleftrightarrow D,$$

rather than the individual conditions $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$.